# Spam in tag wiki excerpt - is user dealt with?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, spam

In reviewing edits I came across a tag wiki except edit which introduced spam, from a 1-rep user with no questions or answers (account was 37 minutes old when I checked).

If the edit is successfully rejected as spam, is there an automatic mechanism to review the user?

If it is not successfully rejected...?

Comment: Not only do we get to deal with the spammer, but s1m0n has some ['splainin' to do](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7481407)

Comment: Robo reviewin mofo

Comment: At least the one (same company) I found @LittleBobbyTables also got to, so that got rejected. User is now anonymous. Just want to know if it is automatic, or what to do if not?

Comment: What's wrong with an advert for water heater resellers from Jakarta as a wiki for the POST tag?

Comment: Now we see why repeated approval/decline is a must. There will always be a user trying to abuse the system.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not automatic. If you come across a spammer that is doing this and hasn't been destroyed, let us know via a custom flag that points to the edit. You can do this on either the post they tried to vandalize or some random post if they were doing this on a wiki.

That's what was done in this case, and I destroyed the spammer and banned the one reviewer who approved this as a result. Even if you just see someone approving obvious spam in a review, it can be helpful to let us know so that we can look into their review history and take action if needed.

Moderators have a query we can run every day to find spammers that didn't get destroyed (usually because the community took care of their posts while a bunch of us weren't around), but that doesn't catch people spamming in suggested edits. Those we might need to be made aware of via flags.