# What to do when a suggested edit modifies code in a way to cause harm

Tags: discussion, edits

While reviewing suggested edits, I just came across an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424539/how-can-i-smooth-out-my-css3-animation). I already rejected it as "causes harm" but want to know if there should be taken any measures regarding the user (member for 1 day) who suggested this edit.
Until now, every suggested edit that I rejected as "causes harm" was only a test.
The edit in question replaced a CSS logo animation with a different animation of graphical content I don't want to describe any further. I guess high rep users are able to check the rejected edit. If not, I could add further explanation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First things first: reject the edit. You did that - congrats!

Then check the editor's profile. There may be more abusive edits, listed under their activity. Reject any you find.

If there are a lot of abusive edits, or if it's clear the account was *only* created to make abusive edits, flag one of the edited posts and let a moderator know what's going on - they can quickly reject further edits, and suspend or destroy the account.

Comment: Thank you, I've just checked the editor's profile again and the account was already deleted. Just wasn't sure how to handle this situation as I'm not able to flag for moderator attention when rejecting an edit and there were no other posts by this user.

Comment: @matthias_h you can do a custom flag on one of your own posts, and include the details and link to the user in the text box.

Comment: @BillWoodger Thanks for the advice, wouldn't have thought of flagging one of my own posts to inform a moderator about an issue with another post/user.

Comment: @matthias_h see here, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288780/1927206, even a random post is fine.

Comment: The ability to flag profiles would be nice.